# Query on field of a referenced document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

There are 2 collections 'actors' and 'movies'

example of 1 actor :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("54f38bd9b814dca762778032"),
  name: {
    first: 'Jason',
    last: 'Statham'
  }
}
```

example of 2 movies

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("54f5cbaf4d9f1129335993ef"),
  title: 'Fast & Furious 7',
  actors: [
    ObjectId("54f38bd9b814dca762778032")
  ]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("54f782493e7688c31f75307d"),
  title: 'Parker',
  actors: [
    ObjectId("54f38bd9b814dca762778032")
  ]
}
```

How can I do to find movies with Jason Statham ?
I use Node.js + Express + Mongoose

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's called asking for a "join" which is something MongoDB cannot do.

You could use an array [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in code after running [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), but of course that needs to pull in "everything" first. You can even specify a query to `.populate()` to match your conditions. But it still means selecting all of the parents.

You could also add the "parentId" to the "child" and that would allow you to query the "child" collection selecting only documents that matched the parent, or "reverse populate" that way, if needed.

Or you can use ["embedding"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) rather than try to reproduce a relational model and use a NoSQL engine for the purpose it was designed. Then what you are asking for works.

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId("54f5cbaf4d9f1129335993ef"),
    "title": "Fast & Furious 7",
    "actors: [
        { "first": "Jason",  "last": "Statham" }  
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54f782493e7688c31f75307d"),
    "title": "Parker",
    "actors": [
        { "first": "Jason",  "last": "Statham" }
    ]
}
```

Sure it duplicated data as compared to a relational and referenced model, but that's the cost of making things efficient.

If you don't want to use a NoSQL storage solution for the benefits of the features it was meant to provide then there will be a cost. Horses for courses as they say, so choose the right tool and use in the the correct way.

Comment: Obviously, I am a MySql user and I am very very new in NoSQL. I am still trying to understand the concepts. 
In a case of users/articles, I need to keep the collection 'users' to login. Is it ok if I copy the entire user's document in the 'authors' array in the article document ?

Comment: @Martial Okay. So which parts are still not clear to you that you need to further understand? Help me help you.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. There is my real need: Users can login to my app with their password. I have a collection 'users' for that.
These users can open requests. I have a collection 'requests' for that too.
I need to list all the requests a user made.
In MySQL this is "piece of cake" (fingers in the nose in Fance ;)) but in mongodb I'm lost.

Comment: Should I put the user's reference in requests or should I make a copy of user's information ?

Comment: @Martial Sorry I missed your comment earlier. But the example here was provided in reference to the context of the question you asked. In the case where you wish to "examine" parts of the "related data" as part or your query expression then the best case is to "embed" that data within the "parent document" as per the context of the answer to the question asked. This answers the question asked. Should you have another question with different conditions then you are best to [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which is the purpose of this site.

Comment: So, to stay in the context of the original question, is it good practice if I keep the collection `actors` with `{name:{ "first": "Jason",  "last": "Statham" }}` and I populate also the field "movies.actors" with the same data (`{ "first": "Jason",  "last": "Statham" }`) for each movie ?

Comment: @Martial It's up to you if you think you need it that way. In general I would say it's either "embedded" or "referenced" as a personal choice and not keep both. The only case I would keep both is if I was embedding a "subset" of relevant data for query purposes, and the other collection had the "full data" about the object

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you know an ID of of an actor **Jason Statham**. All you have to do is to find movies where it has an actor ID `54f38bd9b814dca762778032` which is an `_id` of Jason Statham. This is an example.

```
model.find({actors: "54f5cbaf4d9f1129335993ef"}, function(err, movies) {
    // You get all movies which an actor Jason Statham
});
```

And your movie Schema should be like this.

```
var movieSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    actors: Array
});
```

I hope this might help you.